# Libraries autolinking not working in react-native

Tags: react-native

React-Native app doesn't autolink installed libraries that use native APIs, such as @react-native-clipboard/clipboard. Linking should work since the version of React-Native used is 0.70.5.

I tried deleting the **node_modules** folder, removing all manual linking from native files, and then running the **yarn** command, then running the **./gradlew clean** command in the android folder.

After the actions described above, build occurs, but when the application is opened, it crashes, there is nothing in the console, I open it again, it crashes again.

Dependencies in **package.json**:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.10",
    "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.11.2",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^3.0.4",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@redux-devtools/extension": "^3.2.5",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "centrifuge": "^3.1.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "date-fns-tz": "^1.3.7",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "metro-config": "^0.73.4",
    "prettier": "^2.8.1",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-android-open-settings": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-biometrics": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-config": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.8.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.31.0",
    "react-native-outside-press": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.1.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.3.0",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-touch-id": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.23.1",
    "react-native-yamap": "^4.1.14",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.17.9",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.4",
    "@types/lodash.isequal": "^4.5.6",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.70.8",
    "@types/react-native-table-component": "^1.2.4",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.13",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.25",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^28.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-import-glob": "^2.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.14.0",
    "jest": "^28.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
```

From **app/build.gradle** I removed the following:

```
implementation project(':react-native-config')
implementation project(':@react-native-community-clipboard')
implementation project(':react-native-reanimated')
```

From **MainApplication.java**:

```
import com.th3rdwave.safeareacontext.SafeAreaContextPackage;
import com.swmansion.rnscreens.RNScreensPackage;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.RNGestureHandlerPackage;
import com.reactnativecommunity.asyncstorage.AsyncStoragePackage;
import com.rnfingerprint.FingerprintAuthPackage;
import ru.vvdev.yamap.RNYamapPackage;
// missing some code
new FingerprintAuthPackage(),
new RNYamapPackage(),
new SvgPackage(),
new ClipboardPackage(),
new ReanimatedPackage()
```

From **android/settings.gradle**:

```
include ':react-native-reanimated'
project(':react-native-reanimated').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android')
```

In short, with remove the code above in native files, then the build is successful, the application works as expected. If I remove manual linking, then the build is also successful, but the application crashes on startup.

Comment: deleted sections of the code, I shortened it, if you think that you need to add all 3 files in full, then I will change the question by adding 3 files in full

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to the problem like this:

1. Used **Logcat** in **Android Studio** to find out why the application crashes on startup, there were no errors in the usual debugger.
2. The reason that the application crashes turned out to be in the **react-native-yamap** library used, namely, that this library did not receive a token during initialization.
3. The react-native-yamap library did not receive a token during initialization, since the token was taken from the environment variables, the **react-native-config** library was responsible for this, and the environment variables were not available in the js code.
4. To fix the error of not available environment variables, it was enough to return the following line to the **app/build.gradle** file:
   `apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"`
5. At this point, the application almost worked as it did before I removed the manual linking from the files, except for one thing: the icons from the **react-native-vector-icons** library were not displayed. To fix this issue, I also reverted 1 more line of code in the same **app/build.gradle:** file
   `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"`
6. Done, automatic linking is working, in order for it to start working, it was enough to remove all manual links.